# Block in django doesnt show the another views

Tags: python, django

I'am begginer in Django so please try to understand me.
I have a problem with the blocks in my django project. I created the **base.html** like this

```
{% include 'firmy/header.html' %}
<html>
<body>
<h4>Ostatnio dodane</h4>
{% block firmy %}
{% endblock %}
<h4>Kategorie</h4>
{% block kategorie %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
{% include 'firmy/footer.html' %}
</html>
```

and {%block firmy%} showing me every records what I want from another file but the {%block kategorie%} showing nothing.
in **views.py** I have the code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Witryna, Kategorie
from django.utils import timezone

def widok_strony(request):
    firmy = Witryna.objects.filter(data_publikacji__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('data_publikacji')
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_strony.html', {'firmy': firmy})

def widok_kategorii(request):
    kategorie = Kategorie.objects.all().order_by('glowna')
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_kategorii.html', {'kategorie': kategorie})
```

and in **urls.py** i have the code :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.widok_strony, name='widok_strony'),
    url(r'^$', views.widok_kategorii, name='widok_kategorii'),
]
```

and on the end **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Kategorie(models.Model):
    glowna = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Kategoria')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Kategoria'
        verbose_name_plural='Kategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.glowna


class Witryna(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(default="", max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Nazwa strony')
    adres_www = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Adres www')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Przyjazny adres url')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Adres e-mail')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=3000, verbose_name='Opis strony')
    kategoria = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    data_publikacji = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data publikacji')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Strona www'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony www'

    def publikacja(self):
        self.data_publikacji=timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa
```

and **widok_kategorii.html**

```
{% extends 'firmy/base.html' %}

{% block kategorie %}


{%  for kategoria in kategorie %}


<p>{{ kategoria.glowna }}</p>


{%  endfor %}
{% endblock kategorie %}
```

Really I don't know where is the problem but when I open the browser on localhost:8000 the I can't see the details from class Kategorie.

Comment: Please differentiate the url pattern in your urls.py file first. They both are same.

Comment: Also include your `widok_kategorii.html`  file above.

Comment: Hmm Rajan could You write me how it will be correct to differentiate that url patterns?

Comment: `urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^strony$', views.widok_strony, name='widok_strony'),
    url(r'^kategorii$', views.widok_kategorii, name='widok_kategorii'),
]` Now you can access them at http://localhost:8000/kategorii

Comment: widok_kategorii.html is included

Comment: ok but I want to show the Kategorie as main page like localhost:8000 not as a subpage. Thats why I create base.html

Comment: So just change the url pattern for strony only.

Comment: I removed the strony and url pattern is: urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$', views.widok_strony, name='widok_strony'), url(r'^kategorii$', views.widok_kategorii, name='widok_kategorii'), ] but when i open localhost:8000 I have the records from class Witryny but I dont have the records from kategorie.

Comment: `urlpatterns = [ url(r'^strony$', views.widok_strony, name='widok_strony'), url(r'^$', views.widok_kategorii, name='widok_kategorii'), ]` Now you can access http://localhost:8000

Answer (score 1):

You have a huge misconception about how views and URLs work.

A URL can only be served by one view. That view will be entirely responsible for creating the response, which it usually does by rendering a single template. You need to pass all the information for your template from that view.

Comment: So ok now I understand. I can have only one main view. How can I include the another 'view' in to my base.html? Like in that case now I have kategorie as a main view, and what can I do to show the widok_strony on the base.html?